# Replace value in dataframe on condition with a different type in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to replace values in my dataframe lower than 5.5 with 'insufficient' and higher than 5.5 with 'sufficient' using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

df['test'] = np.where(df['grade'] > 5.5, 'sufficient', 'insufficient')
```

This gives me the following error: 
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

How do I replace my float dataframe values with strings?

Answer (score 0):

Check `df['grade']` include string type values. 
Or, try `df['grade'].astype(float) > 5.5`